# Switching Stylesheet's on Click and then using Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, stylesheet

Okay, So I basically have a HTML page, that will have two images on. The user can then click on one of those images and it will take you to the next page. Each image will take you to the same next page but depending which one you choose it changes the colour scheme.

This the HTML I used for it :

```
<a href="LetterFromEditor.html" onclick="changeCSS('stylesheet1.css', 0);"><img    class="cover" src="cover1.png" /></a> 
<a href="LetterFromEditor.html" onclick="changeCSS('stylesheet2.css', 0);"><img class="cover" src="cover2.png" /></a>
```

This then calls the following script:

```
 function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) 
 {

    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("stylesheet1.css").item(cssLinkIndex);

    var newlink = document.createElement("stylesheet2.css")
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
 }
```

However, this doesn't seem to change anything, it keeps with orignal one set which stylesheet1.

I also need to find a way to use cookies in order to know which one user choose when you go next page and not go back to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newlink = document.createElement("stylesheet2.css")
```

to

```
var newlink = document.createElement("style")
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what you need to do. this oblivously doesn't work because the referenced stylesheets dont exist and the cookie.js file isn't loaded as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/UKLQ8/1/

```
HTML
```

needs the select statement or other methods to select the stylesheet

```
CSS
```

The external stylesheets need to have rel="alternate stylesheet" and the title="???" attributes

```
JavaScript
```

Use jQuery to process the request